# Any closed 3-manifold is a boundary of some compact 4-manifold.

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, geometric-topology, surgery-theory

I knew this is true:

> Any closed, oriented $3$-manifold $M$ is the boundary of some oriented $4$-manifold $B$. See this post: https://mathoverflow.net/q/63373/27004/

I heard this statement is true:

> - Any closed 3-manifold is a boundary of some compact 4-manifold.

Can one show this and explain it intuitively?

Comment: Relevant: http://www.map.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/Unoriented_bordism

Comment: I think $M$ is an integral surgery of a link, and that framed link also determines a 4-manifold whose boundary is $M$. I guess the intuition is that adding a handle corresponds to a surgery on the boundary.

Comment: @Max That only works in the oriented case, but [here](http://sci-hub.tw/https://www.jstor.org/stable/2159598) is an argument for the unoriented case in the same spirit.

Comment: As Max said.  For more specific terminology, you're combining the Lickorish-Wallace theorem with the 4-dimensional (Kirby calculus) interpretation of the diagram.